# Entity Framework - Conext.tt and Model.tt files missing

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and adding a 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' item to my Azure Function for a Database table and only two out of the four files I was expecting were generated automatically. Solution explorer screenshot below of what was created vs expectations. What I am I missing so the Entity Class and Context files will generate automatically?

I have Visual Studio version 16.11.5 installed and I am using Entity Framework version 6.4.4

**What was created**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOcm2.png)

**What I was expecting**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMfk1.png)

Comment: You should switch to Code First: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

Comment: After some trial and error, I was able to use a database first approach by (1) Adding a separate Class Library (.NET Framework) project to the solution with my Azure Function (2) Adding the ADO.NET Entity Data Model within the separate class library (3) Adding a reference to the project in my Azure Function (4) In the Azure Function > local.settings.json adding the connection string. Testing locally with postman the function works but not when I deploy to the portal, "required providerName missing from the connection string. Do you how to setup the connections string in the portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The problem I had was I was creating the Entity Model within my Azure Function. I created a separate .NET Framework Class Library and all the model files created as expected.